# Is an abelian subgroup of a finitely generated group finitely generated?

Tags: group-theory

Let $H <G $ be groups, G finitely generated and H abelian. Is H then finitely generated?

Comment: ${\mathbb Z} \wr {\mathbb Z}$ is an example in which this fails.

Comment: @DerekHolt What's ${\mathbb Z} \wr {\mathbb Z}$?

Comment: The wreath produce of ${\mathbb Z}$ (the infinite cyclic group) with itself. You take a direct product $N$  of infinitely many copies $Z_i$ of ${\mathbb Z}$ indexed by $i \in {\mathbb Z}$, and then form a split extension $G=N \rtimes {\mathbb Z}$ where the action of $ {\mathbb Z}$  on $N$ is to permute the $Z_i$ regularly. Then $G$ is a $2$-generated group, but $N$ is abelian and not finitely presented.

Comment: For a finitely presented example, take the normal closure of $\langle x \rangle$ in the Baumslag-Solitar group $\langle y,x \mid y^{-1}xy=x^2 \rangle$.

Comment: Another finitely-presented example is Thompson's group F.

Answer (score 7):

The Higman-Neumann-Neumann Embedding Theorem states that any countable group G can be embedded into a group generated by two elements. Now let H=$\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: That's overkill!

Comment: I believe you mean embedded into some group generated by 2 elements. (The only abelian subgroups of free groups are cyclic)

Comment: Yes of course. I've edited.